# This query for creating tables works on dev but not on live

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, windows-server-2003, sql-server-2012

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableName](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [URL] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [User] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
```

it works on development environment which is SQL Server 2005 but doesn't work on SQL Server 2012 and gives this error,

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Line 3: Incorrect syntax near
>   'max'.

EDIT

2012 is actually 2000 but Network admin did something so that I can connect to it using 2012 management tool studio

Comment: does your database have compatibility level > 80?

Comment: what does that mean, I was reading for some posts that it should be 90 but I am not sure what impact it will gonna make on live database

Comment: it means you have a database which was restored from SQL Server 2000. (or created with compatibility level 80). the impact of changing is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx In my experience, the impact is usually little to none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is when user is tring to attempt to run query or procedure or logic which is not compatible with previous version of the SQL Server. When SQL Server 2000 is upgraded to SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008, the database object compatibility should be also upgraded to next version. When database compatibility is set to previous version and they are attempted with procedure of newer version they will throw above error.

**Fix/Workaround/Solution:**

Change the database compatibility level using following command.

```
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel 'DatabaseName', 90
```